# How to get customer address, email and phone after successfull registration

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, customer, customer-account, registration

I have an **Observer** for **customer registration** which sends an email to the admin on success. My registration form has all address fields. Sending the mail works already.

Customer Name, StoreName and Company I have already but I still need the complete address data: **street, ZIP, country** ,**phone**, **email** to send it in my mail.  **How can I retrieve this data?**

Can anyone help?

Comment: where you are calling your observer? After placing order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   $customer=Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($observer->getEvent()->getCustomer()->getId());
        $email=$customer->getEmail();
        $address = $customer->getAddresses();
        foreach ($address as $item) {

                $country=$item->getCountry();
                $zip=$item->getPostcode();
                $street=$item->getStreet();
                $telephone=$item->getTelephone();

            }
        }
```

You can get the address details like this.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works almost perfect. The only data that does not show as it should is the street, the it prints **Array** in my mail. Do you know what is the issue with the street?

Comment: the street I got in the end with $street=$item->getStreet(-1);

Comment: how to add this? need to create observer?