# Magento1.9 : How to get customer email in success page

Tags: magento-1.9

Am registering new customer and redirected to success page after registration.I want to show the guest customer email in success page.

Success.phtml

```
        $customerEmail = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getEmail();
        echo $customerEmail;
```

This is not working, because am not logged in. Can anyone help me

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203593/how-to-get-customer-address-email-and-phone-after-successfull-registration

Comment: @MohitPatel  we need to create observer or directly we can call that code in phtml page

Comment: on my experience yes.but try code on phtml file

Comment: @MohitPatel   Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getEvent() on null  got this error after placed

Comment: i am not sure but try this `$customerEmail = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')getCustomer()->getEmail();
echo $customerEmail;`

Comment: not in order success page ...it is for after registration.